# array_rand not working as expected in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random, php-5.6

I was playing around with PHP as I've just begun my training in it. I came across the array_rand function that returns random indexes and you can control how many random indexes you want. But what if the number of random indexes is kept equal to the actual length of the array? I tried it and the result was surprising.

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$temp = array_rand($arr,6);
foreach($temp as $r){
    echo $arr[$r]." ";
}
?>
```

So, I'm randomizing all the indices and printing the same array once again, but in the order that array_rand returns. Please note that I'm not looking for an alternative for this piece of code as I was solely practicing. What I want to know is why the random function returns Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 ) [if you print the array_rand result]? Why is it not random in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_rand` is to pick some random indexes from a given array. For example it may gives you 1,3,4 indexes or 3,5,6 indexes. But not 5,2,4 (At least the purpose of the function is not that).

If you want to randomize indexes for an array you have to use `shuffle`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it. So basically, although it returns random indexes, they are still in order (ascending, as far as I have observed). So if the number of indexes is equal to length of the array, they won't be random at all. Brilliant, thanks for bringing this in my radar. 

I'll try the shuffle function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more step after arry_rand, shuffle(); so your code will be:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
$temp = array_rand($arr,6);
shuffle($temp);
foreach($temp as $r){
    echo $arr[$r]." ";
}
?>
```

because as pre. answer explained the mean.